# Not able to copy configurations dependencies after upgrading Gradle plugin for Android Studio to 3.0.1 and Gradle to 4.1

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I used to copy 'compile' dependencies to a specific folder using this simple gradle task :

```
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into "$project.rootDir/reports/libs/"
}
```

But it stopped working just after upgrading my Android project using gradle plugin 3.0.1 for Android Studio and Gradle tool to 4.1. As the dependency configuration 'compile' is now deprecated by https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#new_configurations I changed it to 'implementation'. However, I am not able to use my copyLibs task as resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed as per Gradle build error output :

```
$ ./gradlew.bat clean build

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:copyLibs'.
> Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
```

See following my current build.gradle file for app module : apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "newgradle.com.testingnewgradle"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into "$project.rootDir/reports/libs/"
}
build.dependsOn copyLibs
```

If I use 'compile' it works but I would like to be compliant with the latest recommendation on this plugin the usage.

I need help to upgrade my copyLibs task in order to work as before upgrading my enviromment.
I was using gradle plugin 2.2.3 for Android Studio and Gradle tool 2.14.1.

Comment: See aslo a ticket raised from a collegue at https://discuss.gradle.org/t/not-able-to-copy-implementation-dependencies/25344

Answer (score 95):

instead of using `configurations.implementation`, the best option is to use `configurations.runtimeClasspath`.

You can also think about:
compileClasspath
default

Comment: Actually, this is a more elegant solution. Simply replace `configurations.compile` by `configurations.compileClasspath` and it works just fine (for me at least).

Comment: It says: `Could not get unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.`. Did I miss something? The same for `compileClasspath`. My code looks the same except it is a library not an app.

Comment: @Bot it has been a few months so I don't really remember how I solved it. I needed to include all dependencies in maven/artifactory and that is working for me now. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @kristyna, I upgraded the gradle plugin to 3.1.2 and it worked for me. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: `configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }` worked well for me (for android `java-library`)

Comment: I also suffer for Could not get unknown property 'runtimeClasspath' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer. Answer with setting configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true) worked for me instead.

Answer (score 37):

I make the configuration resolvable, so there is no exception when getting the dependencies

```
configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
configurations.api.setCanBeResolved(true)

println configurations.implementation.resolve()
println configurations.api.resolve()
```

Comment: This is the cleanest solution in my opinion! +1

Comment: Where would you put this code in your `build.gradle`? I keep getting the error `> Cannot change strategy of configuration ':app:api' after it has been resolved.` when trying to add it.

Comment: Hi, in any task, like this, in front of another configurations or just in front of :):
task copyAndroidNatives() {
...
    configurations.implementation.setCanBeResolved(true)
    configurations.api.setCanBeResolved(true)
    configurations....

Comment: `setCanBeResolved(true)` is now deprecated and intended to be removed in Gradle 9.0.

Answer (score 17):

Another suggestion.

I created my custom config and then used it as `configurations.customConfig`:

```gradle
configurations {
  customConfig.extendsFrom implementation
}
```

The copy task must be correspondingly edited:

```gradle
task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.customConfig
    into "$project.rootDir/reports/libs/"
}
```

Comment: I was super skeptical about this solution but it actually works.

Comment: I understand that this is in fact the correct solution. Gradle 6.4 already suggests `[...] Resolving dependency configuration 'implementation' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
  Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'implementation' should be resolved.` The corresponding task `copyLibs` will copy `from configurations.customConfig`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `from configuration.customConfig`?

Comment: It should. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't look as if there's a way to acquire the list of `implementation` dependencies and the `compileClasspath` mentioned at [the Gradle ticket](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/not-able-to-copy-implementation-dependencies/25344) Rafael posted won't work if you're working with Android directly, like my case where I need the dependencies to be exported so that [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/) can package them up for release.

So.. it looks like the only solution in this case is to use the deprecated `compile` type.

Answer (score 7):

This probably won't help or have a better way to solve but...

You can put your dependencies in a way that is possible to copy doing the following:

```
android { ... }

// Add a new configuration to hold your dependencies
configurations {
    myConfig
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    // Now you have to repeat adding the dependencies you want to copy in the 'myConfig'
    myConfig fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    myConfig 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    myConfig 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    ...
}

task copyLibs(type: Copy) {
    // Now you can use 'myConfig' instead of 'implementation' or 'compile' 
    from configurations.myConfig 
    into "$project.rootDir/reports/libs/"
}
```

This also helps if you have a Jar task that stops placing the dependencies in to the jar file because you changed from `compile` to `implementation`.

You can use:

```
from {configurations.myConfig.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
```

Instead of:

```
from {configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }}
```

Comment: With `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'` and `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10-all.zip`. I'm not sure if it stills work...

Comment: If you do what you are suggesting you should receive some sort of duplication error. Like, "Duplicate class android.arch.core.internal.SafeIterableMap".

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error after upgrading from gradle 5.5 to 5.6, and it happens when I try to sync the project in intelliJ.

Thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17976550/2089675) on another question, I solved it by applying the [`idea`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html) [plugin](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.jetbrains.intellij) to all projects and then running `gradle cleanIdea` and after that everything started working again.

Another day, another #inexplicable solution to a problem.

Answer (score 0):

there is some documentation about this, at least at this moment. You can not directly use 'implementation' configuration, but only use one that extends this. Now you can create a custom configuration, but there are preconfigured extensions already, like 'compileClasspath'.

compileClasspath extends compileOnly, implementation
Compile classpath, used when compiling source. Used by task compileJava.

Documentation is here: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management