# How to make a Jar file with dependencies by Gradle 7.0+?

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies, build.gradle

My current `jar` in `build.gradle` is like below:

```
jar {
manifest {
    attributes "Main-Class": "hoge.Main"
}
    from configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

and working well.

However, I have a message from Gradle (maybe since 6+?)

This is the actual message:

```
The compile configuration has been deprecated for dependency declaration. This will fail with an error in Gradle 7.0. Please use the implementation configuration instead.
```

The part `configurations.compile` is deprecated.

How can I update it?

If I changed

```
jar {
manifest {
    attributes "Main-Class": "hoge.Main"
}
    from configurations.implementation.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

Gradle says `> Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed`

Answer (score 13):

You need to replace `compile` by `runtimeClasspath` in your case.

In previous Gradle versions, `compile` had too many responsibilities:

- Declare dependencies
- Resolved as the compile classpath
- Exposed to consuming projects

It has been replaced by `implementation` for dependency declaration, it also needs to be replaced by something for resolution.

However in your case, you most likely want to package the *runtime* dependencies and not the compile ones. Hence you should use `runtimeClasspath` as the configuration to resolve. And not `compileClasspath` which would not contain any `runtimeOnly` dependencies.

Answer (score 11):

For others wanting to upgrade their Gradle configuration to the 7.0+ format, note that simply replacing `compile` with `implementation` or `api` will likely bug out if you use the `java` plugin. You need to be using the `java-library` plugin. [Documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html).

Make sure that in your `gradle.config` you replace:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

with:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
```

You use `implementation` for non-transitive dependencies, and `api` for transitive ones (if the dependencies are consumed directly by dependents of your project).

Answer (score 4):

The `compile` configuration has been deprecated in favor of `implementation`.

See [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations).

Comment: I know it. I asked how to update my code for the deprecation.

Comment: @kensuke1984 How to do it is to replace all use of `compile` with `implementation`

Comment: yeah Thank you but when I did it, I have "> Resolving configuration 'implementation' directly is not allowed"

Comment: @kensuke1984 you are now asking a new question. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47910578/not-able-to-copy-configurations-dependencies-after-upgrading-gradle-plugin-for-a

Comment: `compile` to `implementation` has been a major change.

Comment: Thanks... https://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/  I finally use it. I wonder if there are ways to simply do this kind of things without importing it.

Answer (score 0):

May help others. Got this to work by using `java-library` plugin and as mentioned in https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_library_plugin.html
runtimeClassPath is not consumable but resolvable. 
First level dependencies could be collected like :
 `def firstLevelDepdendencies = project.configurations.runtimeClassPath.resolvedConfiguration.firstLevelModuleDependencies.collectMany { it.moduleArtifacts }.toSet()`