# What is appropriate substitution for configurations.compile in newer gradle e.g. version 8.7?

Tags: java, gradle, compilation

I am trying to build a jar from a java project based on an older version of gradle, and getting the following error:

Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

This is due to the following jar configuration:

```
jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    ...
}
```

So I tried to replace `'compile'` with `'runtimeClasspath'`, but that generates a fat jar i.e. a jar which includes all dependencies, and I don't want that.

Would be grateful for your suggestions

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a Jar file with dependencies by Gradle 7.0+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367435/how-to-make-a-jar-file-with-dependencies-by-gradle-7-0)

Comment: A regular JAR without dependencies can be built by running the `jar` task added in the Java plugin.

Comment: Thanks @tgdavies, but I don't think that post applies to my specific case, unfortunately.

The top answer there suggests to use runtimeClasspath instead of compile, but as I mentioned it adds to the jar classes from dependendecies e.g. `log4j, apache commons` etc, and I don't want that.

The second most popular answer suggests to replace java plugin with java-library plugin in gradle.config, but the project I am trying to build doesn't have `gradle.config`. Nor I can find any occurrences in the project of `plugin: 'java'` to replace them with  `plugin: 'java-library'`

Comment: Thanks @Simon Jacobs. Could you please point me to some instructions how to do it?

Comment: Just apply the `java` plugin and type `./gradlew jar` in a terminal from the project root directory ([documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks))